# What's wrong with this e-mail?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, email, startup

I'm going to send an e-mail similar to this to a stranger and am trying to increase the probability that the person on the other side will reply positively (or, ideally, send the floor plan immediately, but I'm less optimistic that THAT will happen than that the person will at least reply to the e-mail and still be interested).

============================================

Hi!

Nice to e-meet you!  I saw your profile on [professional website's name] and thought I'd reach out.  I love New York, haha.  I used to walk through Riverside Park all the time during undergrad   (she lived in NYC for 4 years)
Would you like to rent out [name of company]'s apartments faster and get more eyeballs on them sooner?
My name is [my name], and I represent a Virtual Reality marketing company.  We create 3-D experiences of properties, which would allow y'all's customers to check out [name of company]'s spaces for rent from the comfort of their homes.  If y'all send us a floor plan of an apartment are about to rent out, we will make a virtual tour experience of it and increase the number of interested buyers, speed of deals, etc.!
We firmly believe a partnership would be in both of our best interests.  We love the University of [name of state school] and want Virtual Reality to make it a better community that is more connected and easy for students to find new places to live.

Thank you for your time, and have a great day!
[my name]
[my phone number]

P.S.  I generally respond faster to text messages and/or calls than to e-mails.  I'm also free to meet via Zoom

============================================

Thanks!  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.  I hope reading this entertained you  :-)

Comment: You represent a marketing company, and you want us to help you understand how to market a product of yours. Maybe speak to one of your peers first.

Comment: Everything is wrong about receiving a non-solicited email

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is nothing to do with the site scope.

Comment: Apologies.  I wasn't sure where to put the question.  I guess I should have tried Reddit

Answer (score 1):

As @loztinspace says - there's a lot of informality here, and it's missing some of the "what's in it for me" info that I would expect in a business relationship.

Specific thoughts:

- Remove "y'all" and that you love New York - it's a false familiarity that can be really off putting to some people.
- Great that you say you saw their profile.  It would go a bit farther if you had any specific research you'd done on this company that shows you didn't just google every single rental company in the area.  "I see you have rentals available in XYZ address", "I see that your website mentions ### available units", - as a reader knowing that cold call has actually taken some time to see if my business is any kind of a good fit for what they are offering gives me some reassurance that my time isn't being wasted.
- Where does the money come in?  You're saying "get more eyeballs", but what's the cost here - do you take a cut of the profits from the listing?  Straight fee?  Similarly, do you have any data about the results you'll get by providing this service?  Even if the arrangement is all too detailed and lengthy for this email, give a link to more info on the costs and benefits.
- What specifically do they need to send?  If a "floorplan" is so standard that you can do the 3D tour off of basically anything, then great, I guess you're fine, but I can't easily imagine a reasonable looking tour off of some of the truly hideous floorplans I've seen.  Give some links to examples of what you want and any required file formats.
- Don't bury the lead - "My name is [my name], and I represent a Virtual Reality marketing company. We create 3-D experiences of properties" - make it the first line of the intro.

Figure that the person reading this reads tons of random emails from random people who want to engage in various ways with this person.  Very few of those interactions are as beneficial as they claim to be, and the reader doesn't have time/energy/opportunity to engage in all of them - the goal of this email is to clarify the value while minimizing the time to read.

Also - spend some real time on email spam mitigation - if you're blanket mailing businesses, you're going to trigger spam filters - I don't know much about making sure your email isn't getting spam filtered, but there has to be a whole tech craft to it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you've got a lot out of sequence and some very unprofessional text.

Nice to e-meet you! I saw your profile on [professional website's name] and thought I'd reach out.
My name is [my name], and I represent [your company], who create 3-D experiences of properties for potential renters.  This service would allow your customers to check out [name of company]'s spaces for rent from the comfort of their homes, increasing the number of interested buyers, speed of deals, etc. [enumerate your actual reasons properly]

I used to walk through Riverside Park all the time during undergrad and know University of [name of state school] well.  I am sure we can help [her company] connect the community making it easy for students to find new places to live.

I believe a partnership would help you get more eyeballs on the [company] apartments sooner and rent them out faster.

You can check out some of our work here <demo site, probably not a link as this is a cold call>.  If you have a floor plan in XYZ format I'd be happy to show you what it might look like.

If this sounds interesting, please feel free to contact me in a way that works best for you:

Z:

E:

T:

P:

etc.

Something like that anyway.  Tell a story, take their perspective.

Comment: Please do not write answers to questions that are nowhere near on topic for the site.